# Videos not playing sound on any browser

Tags: sound-volume

Mac OS Monterey

So I've tested this so far on Opera and Chrome and for both no Youtube videos returned sound. I then tested non-Youtube videos and those didn't work either. The only volume source that appear to work are non-browser applications(like Spotify). Anyone know a fix for this? I've searched the Opera and Chrome forums extensively and couldn't find a solution that worked.

Answer (score 1):

you have to check sound output settings.

```
System Preferences> Sound > output
```

Your choice's should be "MacBook {air or pro} Speaker"

Answer (score 0):

Update: I think Monterey didn't install correctly because I got another prompt to install it and after that videos are working again. So no answers needed.